# How to aggregate multiple rows from subquery?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

I want to get array of chd_id's for each prod_id,
query below works but only with `limit 1` i want exact result but with multiple rows

```
select 
    prod_id,
    array_agg((select * from jsonb_array_elements(products.prod_prop) limit 1)->>'chd_id')
from products
group by prod_id
limit 10
```

current result:

[image]

Raw value of `products.prod_prop` is

```
[{"val": ["xxx"], "chd_id": 25812}, {"val": ["yyy"], "chd_id": 2342}]
```

Without `limit 1` i get `ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to do this with a lateral join:

```
select prod_id,
       array_agg(t.chd_id)
from products p
  left join lateral (
    select e ->> 'chd_id' as chd_id
    from jsonb_array_elements(p.prod_prop) as t(e)
  ) t on true
group by prod_id
limit 10;
```

The outer join is needed in case there are empty prod_prop values

Apparently the data in the JSONB is sometimes an array and sometimes a plain object. If all "plain objects" are indeed empty values, you can work around that using:

```
select prod_id,
       array_agg(t.chd_id) filter (where t.chd_id is not null)
from products p
  left join lateral (
    select e ->> 'chd_id' as chd_id
    from jsonb_array_elements(nullif(p.prod_prop,'{}')) as t(e)
  ) t on true
group by prod_id
limit 10;
```

If you do indeed mix plain objects and arrays in that column, you need a different approach:

```
select prod_id,
       array_agg(t.chd_id) filter (where t.chd_id is not null)
from products p
  left join lateral (
    select e ->> 'chd_id' as chd_id
    from jsonb_array_elements(case jsonb_typeof(p.prod_prop)
                                when 'array' then p.prod_prop
                                else '[]'
                              end) as t(e)
  ) t on true
group by prod_id
limit 10;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ebdb1a2ffe329738651e4fe93ce959bf)

Comment: I got ERROR: cannot extract elements from an object

Comment: @Sojtin: it works with the sample data you have given us: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=36deac86ca921875e4761fb3c105040d apparently you haven't told us everything

Comment: default value of `prod_prop` is `'{}'::jsonb` is that any relevant?

Comment: Yes, see my edit. But if your json is supposed to store an array, the default value should be `'[]'::jsonb`

Comment: Still the same error, this db is a mess... Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: @Sojtin: the version with the CASE expression should be able to handle any "mess"

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CROSS JOIN` among the table and the subquery generated through use of `jsonb_array_elements()` function :

```
SELECT p.prod_id, array_agg(j.e->>'chd_id') AS chd_id
  FROM products p
 CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(prod_prop) j(e)
 GROUP BY prod_id
```

Comment: I got ERROR: cannot extract elements from an object

Comment: there's no problem @Sojtin . Check [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cb6e43163c68bedf0cb5139caa9ea48b) out please.